# SQL Code for counts over different time periods

Tags: sql, count

[image: Tables]

I need to figure out how to answer this:
Find the number of property views per branch within 1 month, 2 months, and 3 months of client registration in one query.

I'm struggling with how to put this in one query, would CASE be the best way?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just use `UNION`

```
select '1 month' as type, count(*) from tablename where month < 1
union
select '2 month' as type, count(*) from tablename where month < 2
union
select '3 month' as type, count(*) from tablename where month < 3
```

This would yield your counts as 3 different rows.